# Convey more information in exception

Tags: java, exception

I am making a command processing library which takes input and throws an exception if the command cannot be executed for various reasons. I would like to provide helpful information to the user about what has gone wrong and I would also like all the messages to be customisable so it can be used in multiple projects. As I am dealing with user input there are a stupidly large number of things which could go wrong and making an exception for all of them would leave me with more exception classes than actual command processing classes so I have made a few generic exceptions: `CommandException` and `CommandUsageException` and `CommandPermissionException` which extend `CommandException`.

Is it worth making an exception for everything that could go wrong for example `InvalidFlagValueException` or `WrongSubcommandArgumentsException` or is there a better way to do this? Is it a good idea to have an `Enum` for example in the exception to give it more detail?

Comment: I think "it depends."  It might be useful to try it, then just [plan to change it if you don't like it.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PlanToThrowOneAway)  I would personally use at least some different exception classes, just because I think that's good programming, but excess is not a virtue here.

Comment: This excellent article (by founder of SO) gives a good perspective: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html

Comment: @RobP - The takeaway from that would be: "don't throw exceptions at all".  That is a pretty extreme viewpoint if you are coding in Java, and I don't think it helps the OP.

Comment: @StephenC I took it to mean 'don't use them for tons of control flow, or routine codepaths, as they make debugging a bear. Use sparingly.' Of course it's pretty hard to write Java code and not throw any!

Comment: Hmm, that's not what the article says.  It says to never throw exceptions, and convert them all to return values.  Of course you shouldn't use exceptions for normal flow control, but that's well known.  Joel's opinions there really do seem far out there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a pure design decision. You could map out your exceptions and build an inheritance tree with them. Or you could group together into broad exceptions and then ensure that the exception has a String parameter so you could input messages. If I were you I'd do the latter and have the messages in const final variable. Then you could access them from any class so you would have some consistency. I have also using String.format in this sort of case

Fro example the String constant might be

```
public static final String CANNOT_READ = "Cannot read string from %s";
```

and then in the exeption do

```
throws new MyException(String.format(CANNOT_READ, "file");
```

You could then change "file" to be whatever you want depending on the class you are calling from. The String constants gives you some structure but the [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) gives you some customisations.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have a "variables" array in an exception which contains information relevant to the exception and provide a default message that the end user can check for and replace if needed and format with the variables? Almost like what you have done but formatting on catch?

Answer (score 0):

Think about exceptions in this way:

1. Will user of your library do different things for different exceptions?

For example: if you have function/method `createFile`, you can have different exceptions `NotEnoughSpace`, `NotEnoughPermissions`, `FileAlreadyExists` - all require different actions from caller and it is make sense to catch them individually

2. In you case, can you imagine different handler for `InvalidFlag` and `WrongSubcommand`? I suppose both will be syntax fatal errors, but `CommandPermission` - some users will have it, some not, it makes sense to throw it and handle it differently

Answer (score 0):

> Is it worth making an exception for everything that could go wrong for example InvalidFlagValueException or WrongSubcommandArgumentsException or is there a better way to do this?

The way I would answer this would be to try to figure out if you are ever going to need to catch those exceptions individually; e.g. you ever write code that explicitly caught `InvalidFlagValueException` and `WrongSubcommandArgumentsException`.

- If there is a real need to do this, then there is a case for having separate exceptions.
- If there is no real need for this (which only you can judge), then separate exception classes don't offer any advantages.

You have probably already figured out that you can pass extra information by adding message strings, codes, and other information to the exception (and providing getters to retrieve them).

> Is it a good idea to have an Enum for example in the exception to give it more detail?

That's tricky.

- On the one hand, an `enum` is a clean alternative to a code number.
- On the other hand `enum` types are not dynamically extensible.

If you have an `enum` with (say) 10 values, and you want to add an 11th to represent a new error condition, then you *have* to change the source code and recompile the `enum` claSSS.  Fortunately, the binary compatibility rules for enums mean that you can add and/or reorder values without breaking compatibility.  Obviously though:

- Any code that uses the values needs to be aware of the specific ones, and has to be recompiled if it needs to refer to the new ones.
- Removing or renaming enum values will break binary compatibility.
- You now have a "core framework" class that potentially needs to change as new commands are added.  That is an issue if the commands are intended to be "pluggable" / written by 2nd and 3rd parties.

But if those practical constraints are acceptable, then using an `enum` for error codes is a reasonable design choice.